# How to measure complexity of a string?

Tags: .net, algorithm, string, complexity-theory, approximation

I have a few long strings (~ 1.000.000 chars). Each string only contains symbols from the defined alphabet, for example

```
A = {1,2,3}
```

Sample strings

```
string S1 = "1111111111 ..."; //[meta complexity] = 0
string S2 = "1111222333 ..."; //[meta complexity] = 10
string S3 = "1213323133 ..."; //[meta complexity] = 100
```

**Q** What kind of measures can I use to quantify the complexity of these strings? I can see that S1 is less complex than S3, but how can I do that programmatically from .NET? Any algorithm or point to the tool/literature would be greatly appreciated.

#### Edit

I tried Shannon entropy, but it turned out that it is not really useful for me. I will have the same **H** value for these sequences **AAABBBCCC** and **ABCABCABC** and **ACCCBABAB** and **BBACCABAC**

---

[This is what I ended up doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116265/706456)

Comment: Do you mean [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))?

Comment: I tried that, but it turned out that it is not really useful for me. I will have the same **H** value for these sequences `AAABBBCCC` and `ABCABCABC` and `ACCCBABAB` and `BBACCABAC`

Comment: in addition to **hammar**'s comment - do you mean Markov's entropy instead of Shannon's entropy? (same wikipedia link)

Comment: @user759588 @hammar thanks for the suggestions, but neither Shannon nor Markov rate(entropy) is a sufficiently good measures for me

Comment: I think that you might find an answer to your question reading :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I considered KC as the first measure, but it is incomputable, that is for a general case it is not possible to calculate the complexity of an arbitary string due to Halting problem (you never know if your solution is the correct one, therefore stop the program => the program will never stop looking for better solutions)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compressing the strings using standard techniques such as zip gives a good indication of the compexity.

Good compression rate ≈ lower complexity
Bad compression rate ≈ higher complexity

Comment: @user759588, sure it is. Step 1: Zip the string, Step 2: Return zipped size divided by original size.

Comment: @aioobe, really? Your step 1 is more like transpacific voyage, dont you think? (metaphor covers both distance and expenses)

Comment: You're saying it's too complicated? Then say that (and read up on what an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) is).

Comment: @aioobe, i'm saying what it is substantial resource wasting and completely opaque. I'm saying this is too crude.

Comment: Take it as a starting point. Read up on compression algorithms and take the bits and pieces relevant for this problem. It should be noted that this is an intricate and tricky problem.

Comment: @aioobe @user759588 I really like this approach. It is a valid algorithm and it is not crude. It is already been tested in physics and actually I have already implemented that for myself, but I was wondering what will be other suggestions. Still your answer is 100% correct.

Comment: +1 this is an algorithm and a rather clever one! If it is too slow try using FastLZ or something similar. Or you compress ist with RLE first and if the output is small then its low complexity. If not, zip it. If the zipped size is small its mid complexity and if zip can't do anything about the size, it's high complexity.

Comment: @aioobe This seems theoretically unsound. Depending on the compression algorithm, isn't the amount of compression already related to the entropy of the string? If entropy of the string isn't a valid measure of complexity, why would a first-order approximation to the entropy be good? Seems silly.

Comment: @oleksii This seems theoretically unsound. Depending on the compression algorithm, isn't the amount of compression already related to the entropy of the string? If entropy of the string isn't a valid measure of complexity, why would a first-order approximation to the entropy be good? Seems silly.

Comment: @Patrick87 compression of a string is a valid approximation of Kolmogorov complexity. See "Keogh EJ, Lonardi S, Ratanamahatana C(Ann) (2004) Towards parameter-free data mining. In:
KDD Conference, Seattle, WA, pp 206–215" and [On data mining, compression, and Kolmogorov complexity](http://www.springerlink.com/content/1536t57kk558606r/)